# О "неправильно" построенном предложении А.С. Пушкина

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, поэзия

Признание (А.С. Пушкин, 1826 г.)

```
Без вас мне скучно,- я зеваю;
При вас мне грустно,- я терплю;
И, мочи нет, сказать желаю,
Мой ангел, как я вас люблю!
```

*И, **мочи нет**, сказать желаю, **Мой ангел**, как я вас люблю!*

1. Вопросы **такие:**

(1) ***Мочи нет*** — обособлено, а почему? **[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)**

(2) **Обращение** можно поместить **между** главным и придаточным предложением?

2. А может быть, мы неправильно понимаем грамматику этого предложения? Здесь вспоминается примечание **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)** о разговорном стиле в СПП:

Пункт 3. Если **главная часть** сложноподчиненного предложения находится **внутри придаточной** (в разговорном стиле речи), то запятая обычно ставится только после главной части (а перед ней не ставится); ср.: Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался… (Г.) — Нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался хозяйством; Но слова эти мне неудобно, чтобы ты сказала… (Герц.) — Но мне неудобно, чтобы ты сказала эти слова.

**Дополнительно**: Почему использован единый знак (запятая и тире): *Без вас мне скучно, — **я зеваю**.*